# How to capture console output from TDUMP.EXE?

Tags: delphi

TDUMP.exe is file dumping utility from Delphi RAD Studio.  If I run

```
tdump.exe myapp.exe
```

It will return some information about the myapp.exe.

I want to capture the console output of tdump.exe to my VCL gui application.  I have tried the `RunDosInMemo` in http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2001/a/bltip0201_2.htm.  The output result isn't same as command line console output.  It always return:

```
ERROR: Can not open output file myapp.exe.
```

And myapp.exe file will be overwritten.

Running other console command with `RunDosInMemo` works as expected but not Delphi tdump.exe.

Any ideas why redirect console output doesn't work with tdump?

I am using the following code to invoke `RunDosInMemo`:

```
RunDosInMemo('tdump.exe ' + ParamStr(0), Memo1);
```

Comment: I am running with full path on myapp.exe: `RunDosInMemo('tdump.exe ' + ParamStr(0), Memo1)`

Comment: Having looked into this a little, I think you have identified a problem with tdump. I think you may need to redirect to a temporary file and then read that file into memory as a workaround.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Perhaps this is the only workaround solution so far.  Can I use dumpbin utility to do `tdump -em.bpl myapp.exe`?

Comment: How does dumpbin come into it? Did you mean that?

Comment: A possible workaround could be ShellExecute('tdump.exe ' + ParamStr(0) + ' >> out.txt') and then Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('out.txt');

Answer (score 0):

ParamStr(0) returns the full name to your exe including path that may contain spaces that needs to be quoted. Try:

```
RunDosInMemo('tdump.exe "' + ParamStr(0) + '"', Memo1);
```

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Maybe there are other reasons too but the error message "Can not open output file myapp.exe" that OP posted is what happens when you enter something like "tdump c:\path withspace\myapp.exe".

Comment: You get the same message even when you put the quotes in. I believe that there is a real problem with tdump here.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde: My app path doesn't contain space.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan With "Turbo Dump Version 6.4.1.0" I don't get the error message when using quotes.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde You are running tdump from the command line. Run it the exact same way Chau is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

As evident from the error message 'tdump' gives, it is not trying to read the contents of the file name you pass to it, on the contrary, it takes the filename for output.

What 'tdump' actually expects is to read file contents from its 'stdin'. The code you linked in the question is not suitable. You need to create at least two pipes, write contents of the input file to the write end of 'tdump's standard input and read 'tdump's output through the read end of the output pipe.

But this is not required, you can tell 'tdump' to read the file that's passed with an argument, not from stdin. Issue a `tdump -?` at a console and see the help. You'll notice this option:

> -ns     Disable support for redirecting stdin

You just need to change your call to make your procedure work:

```
 RunDosInMemo('tdump.exe -ns ' + ParamStr(0), Memo1);
```

Comment: If it seems to be hanged, that's because populating the memo with the method in the code will take infinitely long. Test with f.i. `tdump.exe -ed -ns ` to verify it working.